# hflex is not working in zk version 9.0.1.2

Tags: zk, zul

```
<hlayout width="100%" height="100%">
    <grid height="100%" sclass="farm-form-grid" hflex="1" xmlns:ca="client/attribute" ca:data-scrollable="false">
        <columns>
            <column width="2.2%" align="right" height="28px"/>
            <column width="34%" align="left"/>
            <column width="57%" align="left" />
        </columns>
        <rows sclass="farm-sale-rows">
            <row sclass="">
                <hlayout>
                    <label value="*" sclass="farm-label" />
                </hlayout>
                <hlayout>
                    <label value="Map Layer:" sclass="farm-label "/>
                </hlayout>
                <hlayout>
                    <textbox id="mapLayerTextbox" instant="true" sclass="intboxwidth"/>
                </hlayout>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </grid>
</hlayout>
```

- I have used hflex="1" in grid to divided in two section.
- But not able get the two section within the hlayout.

Comment: hflex is used to fill the horizontal space of a component's parent container. Since your code only shows one grid in the `hlayout` it will fill out all the space of it's parent. If you want 2 grids (for instance) sharing `hlayout` space you need to do something like:
`<hlayout><grid hflex="1"/><grid hflex="1"/></hlayout>`
Please provide more detail if I have misunderstood your problem.

Other observations:
- within the `row` tags you don't need to wrap each component in a `hlayout` component. They will be laid out horizontally automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. But I have two grid as you mentioned. In zk version 8.5.0 it was working fine but after I upgrade the version to 9.0.1.2 design got change in my whole project where this hflex=“1” is used.

Comment: Another observation I forgot to add in my original comment: Be wary of using width/height% and vflex/hflex in a single component configuration. Use one or the other. I prefer it to be consistent across the whole zul file.

Comment: As you describe, I put 2 grids based on your code and it still works as expected. Please check this example https://zkfiddle.org/sample/jggcev/1-2-grids-in-hlayout-with-hflex
Could you post a reproducible code for the 2-grid hflex issue?